# ExtGWT vs ExtJS

Tags: extjs, gxt

1. When starting a new application, what are the things that you weight out in order to decide whether to go with ExtGWT or ExtJS?
2. For a programmer that knows both Javascript and Java, what is best to choose?
3. Are there still performance issues with ExtGWT compared to ExtJS - back in 2008 people said that ExtGWT is slow for adding a large number of DOM nodes compared to ExtJS but they enjoyed the debugging support ExtGWT provided while in ExtJS debugging is hard and painful
4. How do you find development in ExtGWT compared to ExtJS? Is the compile time of an ExtGWT app an issue - I saw it takes about 10-15 seconds to generate the JS classes while in ExtJS this is not an issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) If you want to program in GWT or if you want to program in one language in your entire stack you use ExtGWT.

2) Whatever you're more comfortable with. Note with GWT you can still write your own JSNI methods and write Javascript there

3) No I would not think there are many performance issues compared to ExtJS. The GXT debugging support is great.

4) With ExtGWT you get the benefits of the tooling support for Java and the strong typing if that's your thing.

Comment: Yes, debugging, strong typing and tooling support are good pros of GWT. Thanks for pointing them out.

Comment: You can program in one language while using ExtJS. Just find an all js stack like node.js or ringojs.